# Google apps script NewTask is created without a title

Tags: google-apps-script

Since couple of weeks the following piece of coding creates a new task under my google task list but without any content in there :

```
var newTask = Tasks.newTask().setTitle("hello");
var inserted = Tasks.Tasks.insert(newTask, id);
```

Has something changed recently ?

Thanks,

Comment: How do you get the `id`?

Comment: The [Class tasks](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_tasks) online documentation says _Last updated January 16, 2013._... Also, no changes related to `Tasks` in the [Release Notes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/release_notes)

Comment: Id is the technical key of the folder where you want to save your task. The id is well retreived because i can always see a new entry but i would expect to see "hello" as a title of my task but it's always blank. The same piece of coding worked well several weeks ago....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me, creating a task "Remember the milk" in my "Test" task list. Adapted from example source for [Class Tasks](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_tasks).

```
function myFunction() {

  var title = "Test";
  var allLists = Tasks.Tasklists.list().getItems();
  var id;
  for (var i in allLists) {
    if (title == allLists[i].getTitle()) {
      id = allLists[i].getId();
      continue;
    }
  }

  var newTask = Tasks.newTask()
      .setTitle("Remember the milk.");

  var inserted = Tasks.Tasks.insert(newTask, id);
  debugger;
}
```